# Show that line $y=x+1$ is a slant asymptote of $y= \sqrt[3]{x^3+3x^2-6x+8}$

Tags: limits

Show that the line $y=x+1$ is the slant asymptote of the graph $y= \sqrt[3]{x^3+3x^2-6x+8}$ by showing that: $\lim_{x \to ∞}$ $\sqrt[3]{x^3+3x^2-6x+8}-(x+1)=0$

Hints:$A^3$-$B^3=(A-B)(A^2+AB+B^2)$ and $(x+1)= \sqrt[3]{(x+1)^3}$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I took the limit of f(x)/x as x->infinity, to find the slope (m) and the limit of f(x)-mx as x->infinity to find the constant (b), and got y=x+1. Not sure what to do from here if that was even correct work to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A= \sqrt[3]{x^3+3x^2-6x+8}$ and $B = \sqrt[3]{(x+1)^3}$

$$f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x^3+3x^2-6x+8}-(x+1)$$
$$=A-B=\frac{A^3-B^3}{A^2+AB+B^2}$$
$$\frac{x^3+3x^2-6x+8-(x^3+3x^2+3x+1)}
{\sqrt[3]{(x^3+3x^2-6x+8)^2}+\sqrt[3]{(x^3+3x^2-6x+8)(x+1)^3}+\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^6}}$$

Take the limit, ignoring the terms lower than $x^3$ in the denominator,

$$\lim_{x \to ∞}f(x)=\lim_{x \to ∞}
\frac{-9x+7}{\sqrt[3]{x^6}+\sqrt[3]{x^3x^3}+\sqrt[3]{x^6}}
=\lim_{x \to ∞}\frac{-9x}{3x^2}=0$$